# Show $f(x)>g(x)$ under conditions on first /second derivatives and the limit of $f-g$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

**Situation**
We have to continuous, differentiable functions $f(x),g(x)$ both mapping $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$.
We know that

- $\exists~ \bar{x}$ such that $f(\bar{x})>g(\bar{x})$
- $0\leq f'(x)\leq g'(x)$
- $g''(x)=0\leq f''(x)$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=0$.

In words: $f$ is larger than $g$ at a point, $g$ grows faster in $x$ than $f$, $f$ is convex while $g$ is linear and the function get arbitrarily close for $x\rightarrow\infty$.

**Question**
Can I conclude that $f(x)>g(x)\forall x$?

**Insights** For $x<\bar{x}$ this is clear, as $g$ declines faster in $x$ than $f$ due to the condition of first derivatives.
For $x>\bar{x}$ this should hold true. Assuming there was a $\hat{x}$ with $f(\hat{x})<g(\hat{x})$, we would need an segment of $f$ where $f''(x)\leq0$ in order to achieve the $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=0$.
I have a problem in writing this up in a rigorous way as I have problems making the connection to the second derivative.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Increasing and convex implies that $f$ goes to infinity. So, I am not really sure that all your assumptions can be simultaneously satisfies. In this case the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @JimmyR. I am not sure whether I understand you right, but I added brackets in the limit condition to clarify things. Is this the point you meant?

Comment: No, this is not what I meant, but perhaps I am confused, so I apologize. If $f$ is increasing and convex, then $f$ goes "quickly to infinity. If $g$ is linear, then $g$ must also go to infinity. But first, how can $g$ go faster to infinity (since g' is constant, while f' is increasing)? This seems impossible. And second, how can they have the same limit, as they actually both have to diverge. I apologize if my comments are irrelevant.

Comment: @JimmyR.Look at the function $h(x)=x^2/(x-1)$ and $k(x)=x+1$ on the interval $(2,\infty)$. We have $0<h'(x)=1-1/(x-1)^2<1=k'(x)$ and $k''(x)=0<2/(x-1)^3=h''(x)$. Furthermore, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(h(x)-k(x))=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}1/(x-1)=0$.
So this would be possible. Convex $f$ doesn't mean necessarily that anything is happening fast. For a nice visualisation go to wolfram-alpha and paste "plot  (x^2)/(x-1) and plot x+1 from x=-10 to 10" into the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is an $x_0 > \bar x$ such that $f(x_0) < g(x_0)$, then for all $x > x_0$, 
$$\int_{x_0}^x f'(t)\, dt \le \int_{x_0}^x g'(t)\, dt\\f(x) - f(x_0) \le g(x) - g(x_0)\\0 < g(x_0) - f(x_0) \le g(x) - f(x)$$
So not only is $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x > x_0$, but it never comes closer together than $g(x_0) - f(x_0)$. But we are also given that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x) - g(x)| = 0$$
But this cannot be, as $$\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x) - g(x)| = \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) - f(x) \ge \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x_0) - f(x_0) > 0$$

Therefore it must be that $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x > \bar x$, even if $f''$ were allowed to drop below $g''$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof. It should be >0 instead of >9, though. I can't edit just one character. Maybe you want to fix it.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.